# How to draw wedge shape with outline in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, drawing

I want to draw a sector of a circle (i.e. a wedge shape) using VBA in Excel (the desktop version from Office 365 ProPlus).  The code below gives me the right shape, but only has an outline on the curved section:

```
Dim myArc as Shape
Set myArc = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeArc, 200, 100, 100, 100)
With myArc
.Adjustments(1) = 0
.Adjustments(2) = 45
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
End With
```

The straight edges don't have an outline, only the curve.  **How can I get an outline all the way around the shape?**  Should I be using a different shape to `msoShapeArc`?  I've tried changing the line colour, weight and visibility using the code below, but it only affects the curved edge, not the straight ones.

```
With myArc
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
.Line.Weight = 1
.Line.Visible = msoTrue
End With
```

I've been able to find documentation on general shape properties, but not which properties apply to which type of shape, and how they actually work to control its appearance.

Comment: If you want a shape with a complete outline then maybe `msoShapePie` would be a better choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.adjustments:

> Because each adjustable shape has a different set of adjustments, the
> best way to verify the adjustment behavior for a specific shape is to
> manually create an instance of the shape, make adjustments with the
> macro recorder turned on, and then examine the recorded code.

This worked for me to create a pie wedge:

```vb
Sub WedgeTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 50, 50, 100, 100)
    With shp
        .Adjustments.Item(1) = -90 'degrees from 3 oclock
        .Adjustments.Item(2) = -45 'degrees from 3 oclock
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the degrees from 3 o'clock are positive (clockwise) or negative (anticlockwise) but can't go beyond an absolute value of 180, so a clockwise +190 degrees would be set as -170 (anticlockwise).